# CiviCRM find all hooks for Event

Tags: civimail, activities

I'm looking for any code to find hooks called for edit activity.

Problem we have occurs whil sending mailing, that tooks 1-2min for one send email, I've made some debug and found that this code slows

**/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php::writeToDB**, Bulk Email activity

```
$activity = civicrm_api3('Activity', 'create', $activity);
Params:
Array(
    [source_contact_id] => 12311
    [activity_type_id] => 19
    [source_record_id] => 2082
    [activity_date_time] => 20231205095113
    [subject] => Zaproszenie
    [status_id] => Completed
    [campaign_id] =>
    [id] => 2660265

)
```

I've found that 'civi.api.respond' for this update takes lot of time...

Is there any way to find wich hooks are called while this api3 call ?
I've added some debug code in civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php::callListeners

```
\Civi::log()->notice('callListener: ', $listener);
```

But it's not helping..

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure how searching for activity create hook would help in your case ( which sounds like a DB optimization issue ).

However, let's  shoot in the dark and see where it leads us: what if you try to disable the "Enable CiviMail to create activities on delivery" option on this page civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1 ?  Would this make your mailings faster and the database more responsive?

Comment: Yes, this makes mails sendin blazingly fast :-) But I wan't to make it work as it should, because we have lot of installs and only on this one we have problem...

Comment: Great to hear a fast band-aid helped. I still think you may want to check things on  your database side first, maybe use some well-known DB optimization tools & techniques and point the finger at civi after that. What I'm saying is, I can't remember experiencing issues like yours across any projects under my management, even on shared hostings. Not sure if it helps, however you may want to explore options here: Settings - CiviMail